# Convergence problem in generalized linear mixed models

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

My outcome variable is called PB, and it is a binary variable: 0 or 1.
I have used generalized linear mixed models (GLMM) because each subject ($n=238$) was measured twice (overall observations = 476)

Using GLMM with a logit function, I have built an empty model with random intercepts. This how I did it in R:

```r
FirstModel <- glmer(data = DATA_LONG3, PB ~ 1 + (1|userId), 
                    family = "binomial")
```

Though when I ran it, I got these warnings:

```r
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0852968 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
```

Just to give points on context:

- Overall there are 476 observations ($n=476$), 62 of them PB = 1, and 414 are PB = 0.
- In the first measurement: ($n=238$), 215 are PB = 1, and 23 are PB = 0.
- In the second measurement: ($n=238$), 199 are PB = 1, and 39 are PB = 0.

Can someone tell me how crucial this problem is for my results, and maybe give me a solution?

Comment: "Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue" is likely the real problem here.  You might want to alter your control parameters, especially the ones in `glmerControl`, and alter the optimizer to Nelder-Mead while upping the iteration count.

Comment: I am guessing that a lot of the PB=0 in the first measurement are also PB=0 in the second measurement, so there is very little change relative to the sample size.  If so, you are close to having, really, one observation per subject, just duplicated, and that will make it hard to estimate a glmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain convergence (which as @ShawnHemelstrand 's answer points out is not your only issue) increase the default value of `nAGQ = 1` to at least 8 to get a relatively stable result:

```
glmer(data = DATA_LONG3, PB ~ 1 + (1|userId), family = "binomial", nAGQ = 8)
```

You gave almost every thing necessary to duplicate your data for use with the model given.  One just needs to find the number of `userId`'s that are 00, 01, 10, and 11.  Those counts are labeled `c00`, `c01`, `c10`, and `c11`.  We find that `179 <= c00 <= 199` and the rest of the counts are then determined.  It turns out that `c00 = 189` and `c00 = 190` result in the same error you had.

Using `c00 = 189` we have

```
library(lme4)

# 176 <= c00 <= 199    176 to 180 gives some different error
#                      181 to 188 and 191-199 works as is
#                      189 and 190 produce same errors as you found
c00 <- 189
c01 <- 215 - c00
c10 <- 199 - c00
c11 <- c00 - 176

obs <- matrix(c(rep(c(0,0), c00), rep(c(0,1), c01), rep(c(1,0), c10),
  rep(c(1,1), c11)), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2)
DATA_LONG3 <- data.frame(userId=factor(c(1:238,1:238)), PB=c(obs[,1], obs[,2]))

glmer(data = DATA_LONG3, PB ~ 1 + (1|userId), family = "binomial", nAGQ = 8)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss- 
  Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 8) [glmerMod]
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: PB ~ 1 + (1 | userId)
Data: DATA_LONG3
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 352.8489  361.1798 -174.4245  348.8489       474 
Random effects:
Groups Name        Std.Dev.
 userId (Intercept) 2.059   
Number of obs: 476, groups:  userId, 238
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
     -3.045
```

Answer (score 4):

##### Answer

To your big question:

> Can someone tell me how crucial this problem is for my results...

Your results are basically meaningless if the model hasn't converged. So you need to fix your regression before moving forward. As to your other question:

> ...and maybe give me a solution?

What I can say is that including random intercepts with few levels can often be a root cause of convergence issues in mixed models. It is often recommended to have at least 5 levels for a random intercept to be useful in mixed models (see Gelman & Hill, 2007, p.247 iirc), though there is no law saying you can use less.

In my opinion, it would be better to simply model Time 1 and Time 2 for each participant as fixed effects, which would be more directly interpretable (perhaps you have an idea of time having some influence on the outcome, so using this coding would answer that more directly anyway).

##### Citation

Gelman, A., & Hill, J. (2007). Data analysis using regression and multilevel/hierarchical models. Cambridge University Press.